# How do I use the "screen" command if I don't know what the ps or tty the program came from?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, tty

I am making a python program that launches on bootup. I would like it so that I can interact with that program via the "screen" command. Then, if I need to talk to the program via a different tty, ssh, or something then I would be able to.

I like to keep it so I can just use a bash script to attach the screen in my terminal, instead of having to look up where it is—as I need other people (who don't use the terminal) to be able to access it.

Comment: As an aside, `screen` sessions belong to a user, so you can't have "other people ... to be able to access it". If it launches at startup the `screen` session will belong to root, not you.

Answer (score 1):

The surest way to attach to the right screen session is for the Python script to write to a designated file to report which `screen` session it is running in.  Think of it as something analogous to a PID file, except that you are reporting the TTY rather than the process ID.  Otherwise, if multiple `screen` sessions exist, there's going to be guesswork involved.

So, when launching the Python process, run

```
echo "$STY" > /var/run/python-proc.screen
```

… or from within the Python program itself,

```
with open('/var/run/python-proc.screen', 'w') as f:
    print(os.environ['STY'], file=f)
```

Then, users can attach to it by running

```
screen -x -m `cat /var/run/python-proc.screen`
```